# Chaining a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, chaining, local-storage

I want to make a function that add an item to my localStorage object. E.g.:

```
alert(localStorage.getItem('names').addItem('Bill').getItem('names'));
```

The first method is getItem which gets the item for localStorage objects... but addItem would be a custom function. This chain of functions would finally alert Bill.

So, how would I make this function chain to localStorage?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  What would `getItem` return?

Comment: getItem should be at the end of the chain, but aside from that it can be done

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `alert(localStorage.getItem('names').addItem('Bill'))`.

Comment: Yes, thatd work also if it returned all the names including Bill...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This is possible** if you **create a wrapper/decorator object** that makes chaining possible. This is how jQuery works for example. But it is **useless in this case**.

I made a possible implementation, though.

But *getItem* will break the chain (so it should always be used at the end).

```
storage().setItem('names', 'Bill').getItem('names'); // or
storage().setItem('names').addItem('Bill').getItem('names'); // or
storage().key('names').value('Bill').set().get('names');
```

**Implementation**

```
(function( window, undefined ) {

var storage = function( key, value ) {
  return new storage.init( key, value );
};

storage.init = function( key, value ) {
  this._key   = key;
  this._value = value;
};

storage.init.prototype = {

  key: function( key ) {
    this._key = key;
    return this;
  },

  value: function( value ) {
    this._value = value;
    return this;
  },

  get: function( key ) {
    key = isset(key) || this._key;
    return localStorage.getItem( key );
  },

  set: function( key, value ) {
    this._key   = key   = isset(key)   || this._key;
    this._value = value = isset(value) || this._value;
    if ( key && value ) {
      localStorage.setItem( key, value );
    }
    return this;
  },

  addItem: function( value ) {
    this._value = isset(value) || this._value;
    if ( this._key && value !== undefined ) {
      localStorage.setItem( this._key, value );
    }
    return this;
  },

  // aliases...
  getItem: function( key ) {
    return this.get( key );
  },
  setItem: function( key, value  ) {
    return this.set( key, value );
  }
};

function isset( value ) {
  return value !== undefined ? value : false;
}

window.storage = storage;

})( window );
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i must be screwing something up tho. I copy & paste your code and then added alert(storage.setItem('names').addItem('Bill').getItem('names')); right below it and im getting a storage.setItem is not a function?

Comment: @Oscar – You forgot the parentheses: `alert(storage().setItem('names').addItem('Bill').getItem('names'))`

Comment: @Oscar Marcel is right, it now creates instances for storage chains, so you need to write `storage()`. I can modify it to be only one object, but it may become less robust.

Comment: Awh, i see, yeah so: alert(storage().setItem('names').addItem('Bill').addItem('Tom').getItem('names')); alerts Tom and so does localStorage.getItem('names'). Almost perfect, but how can i return Bill, Tom, etc in that same alert? Basically, return them in an array? Sorry if this stuff is way over my head. Im trying to learn though... I like this style more than just plain functions...

Answer (score 5):

This is impossible.

If `getItem('names')` returns `Bill`, you can't call `addItem` on it.
It would be possible to add `addItem` and `getItem` methods to every item in the storage, but it would be a *horrible* idea.

Comment: **it is possible** (without augmenting localStorage). see my answer.  Not a very useful case, but a good demonstration of the **decorator pattern**.

Comment: @galambalazs: It's not possible using his exact calls.

Comment: getItem() breaks the chain, that's obvious, but you don't need to add methods to every element in the storage.

Comment: No, there isn't, but what you were trying to do was very jQuery-like in a bad way :D

Comment: How would suggest making an addItem function? if not adding an item is a lot of extra markup. I'd prefer doing it in a DRY way...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing would be to not do this at all :)

If that doesn't work, then there are solutions like modifying the native `getItem` function but that's a really bad idea. The best way would be to write a wrapper around `localStorage`, much like what jQuery does to DOM nodes, and use that wrapper to get and put items in local storage. The wrapper could have an interface like:

```
ApplicationStorage
    getItem()
    setItem()
    key()
    removeItem()
```

Then define acceptable type wrappers like `Array` within `ApplicationStorage` that have methods like `addItem`

```
ApplicationStorage.Array
    addItem()
```

When `applicationStorage.getItem("names")` is called, return an object of `ApplicationStorage.Array` that contains the method `addItem` which will make chaining possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
getItem('names').addItem('Bill').getItem('names')
```

I am confused, how do you get an item that has not been added???

getItem returns an object contains addItem method, and addItem method returns an object contains getItem method

Anyway, have a look the following tutorial.  It does not completely solve your problem, but will give you an idea.

http://guanfenglin.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!4E0822BF6C959B7F!668.entry